# Copying Xcode project files does not work completely

Tags: xcode9.2

When I copy files from one Xcode project to another, the files appear in the destination project and the second Xcode project compiles and works fine. So far everything is ok.

But some of the source files have not been moved into the various folders/directories of the destination project. I think the second project is still pointing to some files in the first/source project.

How to completely move the files from the first project into the destination project folders/directories?

Comment: How do you "_copy files from one xcode project to another_"?

Comment: drag source files from one to another, that is how I did

Answer (score 0):

Thank you the link you gave me helped. I dragged the files from source to destination folder via Finder. Then I deleted the files that went red in destination project and then added the files in respective folders from xcode.